# css: three horizontal dots using :before and :after

Tags: html, css

I want to show three horizontal dots (I've made a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StC3z/))

```
span {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

span:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    content: '';

    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;  
    margin-left: 35px;

    padding: 5px;
}

span:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    content: '';
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;  
    margin-left: 35px;

    padding: 5px;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to achieve this. Also, I want them to line-up horizontally. And I don't understand why they aren't. Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `absolute` positioning, you could use `top` property to position the pseudo generated contents vertically, and play with `left` property for horizontal alignment

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/StC3z/1/)**

```css
span:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px; /* <-- align the circle horizontally */
    top: 0;      /* <-- Added declaration             */
    content: '';

    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px; /* <-- align the circle horizontally */
    top: 0;     /* <-- Added declaration             */
    content: '';
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;    
    padding: 5px;
}
```

In this case there's no need to use `margin` of the pseudo-elements.

Additionally, you could avoid negative values for `left` property to make the circles appear in the right. (**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/StC3z/2/)**).

Answer (score 1):

//using left instead of right in after

```
span {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

span:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;  
    margin-left: 35px;

    padding: 5px;
}

span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px; //using left instead of right
    content: '';
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;  
    margin-left: 35px;
    top: 0;

    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/StC3z/3/)</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<span></span>
```

#### CSS

span {
        position: relative;
        background-color: blue;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 0;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

```
span:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0;
    content: '';

    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;    
    padding: 5px;
}
```